# Does Windows' "turn off hard disk after" setting only affect HDDs or also SSDs?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd

After changing the setting from `0`, it appears to also my SSDs (RAID, if that matters) turn off.

I'm also running Windows 10 if that matters, but the power options menu appears to have carried from Windows 7.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Contrary to the other answer, I am quite sure, well, not absolutely and entirely, but pretty sure it does affect SSDs as well because I always noticed that one of my other SSDs that isn't used as much keeps disappearing from my monitoring software, and almost instantly re-appears when I access the drive thru explorer.

Just because it doesn't have any moving parts doesn't necessarily mean that you can't turn it off, after all both are powered by electricity, and both have a controller that can apparently get a signal to shut-down the device to save a bit of energy. It just seems that you can't easily notice it's shut down because there is no sound and even explorer still counts the drive like it's there and it comes back up immediately so none of these things really give any hint that it would be actually off.